# Wireless Networks showing "device not managed" in Network Manager

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I am using Kali Linux 1.0.6. Recently I have disabled NetworkManager and configured my system to connect to wireless network through Terminal by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and running `wpa_supplicant`.

Now, I want to switch back to NetworkManager UI but I am unable to see any wireless networks. It is saying "device not managed" under Wireless Networks. I tried many solutions which said editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and changing `Managed=true` will solve the issue. But  it didn't solve. I reinstalled NetworkManager even reinstalled wireless modules with no use.

How to get back wireless networks in my NetworkManager UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what is happening here is that some other process owns the wireless chip inside your computer, so NetworkManager isn't allowed to do anything. In this case, that process would be `wpa_supplicant` or whatever is calling `wpa_supplicant` (and acting on the information in `/etc/network/interfaces`).

Instead of randomly installing things, you should stop and think a moment about what caused your problem. The problem appeared when you edited `/etc/network/interfaces`, right? So undo the changes you made in that file. That will stop other processes from wanting ot take control of the network device, thus allowing NetworkManager to do its thing.

Comment: If it is by `wpa_supplicant` how can i stop it? If i stop it my internet is disconnected.

Comment: @Kiran like I said: undo what you did in `/etc/network/interfaces`. yes, your internet will disconnect: when you don't have a daemon running to manage network cards (e.g. when you're switching them), you don't have network access. shocker. it will come back when NetworkManager starts using the card.

Answer (score 2):

By default, if an interface is listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`, NetworkManager will be smart and not touch this interface, to avoid both configuration method to interfere with each other.

Comment the `/etc/network/interfaces` definition concerning your wireless device and restart NetworkManager.